# Class variable within its definition?

Tags: c++, class, variables, scope, mud

This is probably a dumb question. I am trying to make a text-mud. I need each Room class to contain other Room classes that one can refer to when trying to move to them or get information from them. However, I can not do that because I obviously can not declare a class within its definition. So, how do I do this? Here's what I mean when I state I can not do it:

```
class Room {
    public:
        Room NorthRoom;
        Room EastRoom;
        Room SouthRoom;
        Room WestRoom;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I forgot about pointers. They're a new concept to me after being spoiled by the luxurious laziness of high-level languages.

Comment: If you are new to C++, you may want to get [a good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list), even if you have experience with other languages.  In addition to the answers below, take a look at "smart pointers" (you can search here on Stack Overflow or on Google), which make memory management in C++ _far_ simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to have a `Room` member variable. You could use a pointer or reference though.

```
class Room {
    public:
        Room* NorthRoom;
        Room* EastRoom;
        Room* SouthRoom;
        Room* WestRoom;
};
```

Comment: It's more fundamental than the class not being complete.  If it were possible, the resulting class would be of infinite size!

Comment: @Oli: Yep. I've deleted that immediately after the post is submitted as I've realized it is not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure not EVERY room has four children rooms, right? Otherwise the number of your rooms is infinity which is hard to handle in finite memory :-)

You might try

```
class Room {
    public:
        Room* NorthRoom;
        Room* EastRoom;
        Room* SouthRoom;
        Room* WestRoom;
};
```

Then you can have NULL pointers when a room doesn't have children.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Room` needs to have *pointers* to other `Room`s  (that is, `Room*`s).

A class type object (like `Room`) has a size that is at least large enough to contain all its member variables (so, if you add up the sizes of each of its member variables, you'll get the smallest size that the class can be.

If a class could contain member variables of its own type then its size would be infinite (each `Room` contains four other `Room`s, each of which contains four other `Room`s, each of which contains...).

C++ doesn't have reference type objects like Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pointers:

```
class Room {
    public:
        Room* NorthRoom;
        Room* EastRoom;
        Room* SouthRoom;
        Room* WestRoom;
};
```

Probably cause is that class does not yet its constructor, so when you use pointers you init them later, when class has construcotr definition.